# Cannot add a custom PowerPoint Add-In to the ribbon

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-addins

To create an **Excel Add-In (*.xlam)** I follow these steps:

1. Open a new Excel file → Developer → Visual Basic → Insert → Module
2. Insert a most basic [Hello World subroutine](https://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/automating-excel/1264-getting-started.html?start=1)
3. (Excel file) → Save As → Excel Add-In (*.xlam)
4. The add-in is saved at `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Microsoft\AddIns`
5. Open a new Excel file → File → Options → Add-Ins → Excel Addins → Go
6. Click checkbox to enable my Hello addin → OK
7. (Right click on the ribbon) → Customize the Ribbon

Now when I select a drop-down box `Choose commands from` and select the `Macros` option, I see my Hello subroutine listed there. I can add it to the ribbon.

---

When I try to imitate this procedure to create a **PowerPoint Add-In (*.ppam)**, I follow all 7 steps but then I select the `Macros` option in the `Choose commands from` drop-down box and I don't see my subroutine listed there. The column is empty. I thus cannot add my add-in to the ribbon.

What did I do wrong? Why this procedure works in Excel but not in PowerPoint? How can I add my PowerPoint Add-In to the ribbon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerPoint <> Excel.

It *might* work if you declared your add-in subroutines as Public, but the usual way to do this is to add RibbonX code to your PPTM/saved PPAM that creates the buttons etc. you want.

[Adding a macro from PowerPoint add-in to ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842285/adding-a-macro-from-powerpoint-add-in-to-ribbon?rq=1)

The Leaf Creations editor mentioned there is gone, but Ron DeBruin's site is a gold mine of good advice.

Ken Puls et al have a great book on RibbonX coding; it might seem to be out of date but most of the info is still good:

[https://www.amazon.com/RibbonX-Customizing-Office-2007-Ribbon-ebook/dp/B001DIRYWU/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=ken+puls+ribbonx&qid=1557929946&s=gateway&sr=8-1-spell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001DIRYWU)

Comment: The steps I took were so similar in Excel and PowerPoint that I have no idea why the developers decided to deny loading macros from PowerPoint addins while allowed loading them from Excel addins. Very strange. Also I declared my subroutine explicitly as public and it did not help. Thank you for the ribbon coding advice. Though it looks like a bit of work, it seems that it is the only option.

Comment: People think of Microsoft as one huge monolith; in reality, it's more like an empire built of many smaller fiefdoms. The PowerPoint team, in fact, is not even in Redmond with the rest of Microsoft.