# How can I add a new button/ribbon to Powerpoint 365 with VBA and without using any third-party-editor except for notepad?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Well, on a corporate PC I have Powerpoint 365 and no administrative rights. I cannot use any ribbon editor or so.  I created a VBA macro and I want to be able to use this in all presentations. Therefore I saved it as a Powerpoint add-in (ppam). The add-in loads fine, but the sub does not show up under macros. After some reading I found that it is only (somehow) possible to access macros from a Powerpoint-Add-in when you link them somehow to the UI with a new button or so.

So, I think a way to do this could be another auto_open sub in the add-in and within that I could enhance the UI with some customUI xml. But I do not know how and my articles only lead to third party software that I cannot use.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842285/adding-a-macro-from-powerpoint-add-in-to-ribbon)

Comment: @freeflow: Please advise me where you see violation of the guidelines and I will gladly improve my post. This way I do not know to what you refer.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: Thanks, but this is a rather old post and it links to the help of xml editors for the ribbon ui and I cannot use them.

Comment: I use a EmEditor with no problem (personal preference), if you have Notepad, you should be fine. Look to the provided links (in answers and comments) for more guidance

Comment: You might benefit from reading up on the IRibbonExtensibility interface.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.IRibbonExtensibility

Comment: If you follow that link again and visit Ron DeBruin's site you'll find that he does refer to using a third party program, but also describes the XML you'd add USING the program. Same stuff as you'd add using Notepad.

Comment: Thank you all, but @freeflow Please be so kind and help me where I should improve my question. Please point me into the direction what you are critisizing. I would like to improve my post.

Comment: You could try https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @freeflow: I have read that and still I do not see what the problem is. But for some reason you rather want to direct me to guidelines instead of telling me what the problem is from your point of view.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider doing your development on a non-work machine, where you can install other software. While it's possible to revise the Ribbon without a third-party editor, it will be difficult to get it working as expected. Here's an overview:

Since PowerPoint files are zipped, you need a good zip utility. The one included with Windows can unzip, but when re-zipping, it tends to include any top-level folder in the archive, making it non-functional in Office. I've used WinZip and 7Zip with good results.

After unzipping your file, create a new top-level folder beside **rels**, **docProps** and **ppt** folders. Call this folder **customUI**.

Open the top-level *rels* folder, then open the **.rels** file. Add a new relationship like this:

```
<Relationship Id="Rb0bc0a832fad4e57" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com /office/2007/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI14.xml"/>
```

The id number is a 16 digit random hex number, but with **R** prepended to it.

Now open the *customUI* folder and create a **_rels** folder inside it.

If you will be including custom icons, create an **images** folder in the customUI folder. Open the images folder and copy in the custom icon files. These can be, but don't have to be, in .ico format. Office is just as happy to use .png, .bmp or other Office-compatible bitmap format. Transparency is honored, either single-color or alpha-channel.

Open the _rels folder and create a new text file in it called **customUI14.xml.rels**. The content of the .rels file should look like this (this assumes 1 icon is being added):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006 /relationships">
    <Relationship Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="images/IconAddNav.png" Id="IconAddNav" />
</Relationships>
```

**Target** is the location relative to the _rels folder and **Id** is the reference name used in the custom XML.

Create a text file in the customUI folder called **customUI14.xml**. These files should have Windows line breaks (CRLF) and Unicode (UTF-8) encoding.

Here's the start of a customUI14.xml file that creates a new tab that sits before the Design tab on the Ribbon:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="NewTabCallbackOnLoad">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
  <tab
    id="TabNewTools"
    insertBeforeMso="TabDesign"
    label="New Tools">
```

Finally, rezip everything, change the file ending to match the file type you started with, and test.

PowerPoint offers very little feedback for any errors you make, so don't expect to get this working in a hurry. The above instructions will also work for someone using a Mac, since macOS lacks any third-party Office XML editors.

Comment: Wow, @John Korchok: Thank you so much. I just have to ask an additional question. I guess that following your procedure I have to start with a .pptxm and I also rename the zip to a .pptxm again. And how do I get from there to an addin that I can use in every presentation?

Comment: There's no .pptxm file ending, just .pptm. Develop in the .pptm. When it's all done, save as .ppam format to install in the Windows Add-in folder. On a Mac, you would save the .ppam to the PowerPoint Startup folder. Save the .pptm for future revisions, as .ppams are not editable.